# Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop highcharts display using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I trying to display highchart
It displays correct, but angular returns errror *Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop*
**here is controller:**

```
$scope.graphPriority=[
        {value:2},
        {value:0},
        {value: 1}
        ];
    $scope.process = function(graphPriority) {
        return graphPriority.map(function (elem, i) {
            return [i, elem.value];
        });
    };
```

**and html if somebody cares:**

```
<div class="main-inner-pie">
                <highcharts-pie class="hc-pie-1" items="process(graphPriority)"></highcharts-pie>
            </div>
```

What I missed?

**EDITED:**
I tried:

```
$scope.process = function(graphPriority) {
            graphPriority.map(function (elem, i) {
                return [i, elem.value];
            });
        };
```

It's not return error, but not display chart

Comment: Have you seen [the official instruction](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js) for Highcharts with AngularJS? There is also, mentioned in that article, directive for Highcharts that might checkout - github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng